# Where is Update translation?

Tags: 7, updating, i18n-l10n

In `admin/config/regional/translate/update` I found the following message:

> If there are available updates you can click on "**Update
> translation**" for them to be downloaded and imported now or you can
> edit the configuration for them to be updated automatically on the
> Update settings page

The following screenshot reveals more:

[image]

I could not able to find **Update translation** anywhere. What is missing?

Comment: do you have installed l10n_update module?

Comment: No I have. does it important for this portion?

Comment: with l10n_update you can update more easily the string from drupal.org or localfiles

Comment: do you solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you the installation of [Localization update](https://www.drupal.org/project/l10n_update) module.

From the module's page:

> Automatically downloads and updates your translations by fetching them
>   from localize.drupal.org or any other Localization server.

I use this module in all my projects, you can also have the `.po` files in the local server.